# I have multiple carousels on the same page and they have a timer to move the photos automatically. But why is they only showing me six photos?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

I would like to have multiple carousels on the same page and have the photos move automatically every few seconds. There are other ways to do this, but I prefer to solve this one to understand where I am going wrong.

Any advice about the best way to go about this would be great, I'd love to keep it in vanilla js if possible. Thanks for your help!

```js
let index = 0;
const carouselA = document.querySelectorAll('.a');
const carouselB = document.querySelectorAll('.colonica-slide'); // "colonica-slider" example
const carouselC = document.querySelectorAll('.c');
const carouselD = document.querySelectorAll('.d');

carousel(carouselA, carouselB, carouselC, carouselD);

function carousel(n, o, p, q) {

  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    n[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
    o[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    p[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
    q[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  index++;
  if (index > n.length) {
    index = 1
  };
  if (index > o.length) {
    index = 1
  };
  if (index > p.length) {
    index = 1
  };
  if (index > q.length) {
    index = 1
  };

  if (index <= n.length) {
    n[index - 1].style.display = 'block';
  }

  if (index <= o.length) {
    o[index - 1].style.display = 'block';
  }

  if (index <= p.length) {
    p[index - 1].style.display = 'block';
  }

  if (index <= q.length) {
    q[index - 1].style.display = 'block';
  }

  const timeCarousel = setTimeout(function() {
    carousel(n, o, p, q);
  }, 4000);
}
```

```css
.carousel-container {
  max-width: 80%;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px var(--apple-black);
}

.carousel {
  display: none;
}

.text-photo-slide {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel img {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">

  <div class="carousel colonica-slide">
    <img src="./resources/official-photo/colonica-esterno-ingresso.jpeg" alt="">
    <div class="text-photo-slide">Ingresso</div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel colonica-slide">
    <img src="./resources/official-photo/colonica-piazzale.jpeg" alt="">
    <div class="text-photo-slide">Piazzale</div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel colonica-slide">
    <img src="./resources/official-photo/colonica-esterno-tavolo_1.jpeg" alt="">
    <div class="text-photo-slide">Tavolo esterno</div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel colonica-slide">
    <img src="./resources/official-photo/colonica-cucina.JPG" alt="">
    <div class="text-photo-slide">Cucina</div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel colonica-slide">
    <img src="./resources/official-photo/colonica-cucina_2.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="text-photo-slide">Cucina</div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel colonica-slide">
    <img src="./resources/official-photo/colonica-sala_2.jpeg" alt="">
    <div class="text-photo-slide">Salotto </div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel colonica-slide">
    <img src="./resources/official-photo/colonica-camino_1.jpeg" alt="">
    <div class="text-photo-slide">Sala Camino</div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel colonica-slide">
    <img src="./resources/official-photo/colonica-camino_2.jpeg" alt="">
    <div class="text-photo-slide">Sala Camino</div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel colonica-slide">
    <img src="./resources/official-photo/colonica-camino_3.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="text-photo-slide">Sala Camino</div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel colonica-slide">
    <img src="./resources/official-photo/colonica-scale.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="text-photo-slide">Scale</div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel colonica-slide">
    <img src="./resources/official-photo/colonica-stanzagrego_2.jpeg" alt="">
    <div class="text-photo-slide">Camera 1</div>
  </div>


  <div class="carousel colonica-slide">
    <img src="./resources/official-photo/colonica-stanza-grande.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="text-photo-slide">Camera 2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel colonica-slide">
    <img src="./resources/official-photo/colonica-armadi.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="text-photo-slide">Armadi</div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel colonica-slide">
    <img src="./resources/official-photo/casa-sole-2.jpeg" alt="">
    <div class="text-photo-slide">Panchina Panoramica</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please find some free images on the net to make a [mcve]